# Изменить REQUEST_URI ( мало кода, вопрос теоретический )

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, сервер

Есть файл page.php с чатиком в реальном времени на Ajax, который обращается к другому файлу ajaxPost.php с помощью кода:

```
 $("#userArea").submit(function(){
$.post('/ajaxPost', $('#userArea').serialize(), function(data){
    $("#messages").append('<div>'+data+'</div>');

});
```

Если в ajaxPost.php ввести код:

```
echo $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

То выводится слово "ajaxPost" (имя файла ). Вопрос, каким образом можно вывести REQUEST_URI файла, с которого пришёл запрос, в данном случае, с page.php ?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: @Роман Парадеев обнял тебя, мужик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Из [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Следует иметь в виду, что заголовок `Referer` **не гарантирует**, что запрос был выполнен с определённой страницы.

Следовательно, его нельзя использовать, например, в целях разграничения доступа.